# Typescript Declaration Merging fail about Express Request

Tags: typescript, type-extension

When i extend express request, i got this erorr.

```
error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
```

This is my test code that extend request.

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req: Request, res: Response) {
    req.test = 'aa'
    return console.log(req.test)
});
```

For solving it, i already searched a lot and i did it.

Make `types/express/index.d.ts` file. i add typeRoots in `tsconfig.json` like below.

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],
```

This is types/express/index.d.ts file and what did i try.

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        test: string
    }
}

// This is also fail
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        test: string
    }
}

// This is also fail
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        test: string
    }
  }
}
```

Even my `vscode` tell me `req.test` type is string, server show me error.
[image]

This is full erorr on console

```
[nodemon] starting `ts-node src/app.ts`

/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/app.ts(67,9): error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
src/app.ts(68,28): error TS2339: Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

    at createTSError (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434:12)
    at reportTSError (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:438:19)
    at getOutput (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:578:36)
    at Object.compile (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:775:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/app/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

This is my package.json, as you can see my typescript version is 3.9.6

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/app.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
}
```

This is my all tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./types"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  },
  "exclude": [
      "nod_modules",
      "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I spend time and got stress from yesterday. How can i solve it?

Comment: What happens if you try and compile with tsc? `./node_modules/.bin/tsc`?

Comment: @torkel when i execute `.\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd` in same path with tsconfig.json. there is nothing to display

Comment: Then it seems like there's nothing wrong with your TypeScript configuration, and this is instead a problem with `ts-node`. See my longer answer for a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with how you've configured `ts-node`. To keep things simple and also speed up startup I'd recommend adding `-T`/`--transpile-only` to your `ts-node` arguments, such that your `start` script becomes `nodemon --exec ts-node -T src/app.ts`.

This option prevents `ts-node` from running type checks on your code. This has a few benefits:

1. You avoid configuration conflicts between `tsc` (the TypeScript compiler) and `ts-node`
2. `ts-node` starts up much quicker
3. You can run your server even with compiler failures, which is nice in development.

Note that you **never** want to commit or merge code that doesn't compile properly with `tsc`. You can do that by checking this on CI (continous integration) or as a pre-commit hook. If you add `"tsc": "tsc"` to `scripts` in `package.json` you can do `npm run tsc` or `yarn tsc` to compile your code.

You can read more about `ts-node` CLI flags here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#cli-and-programmatic-options

Comment: Thanks to comment. finally there is no error. But yesterday when i check tsc, i only command tsc. when i check tsc /src/app.ts today, i found erros about `node_modules/index.d.ts` error text is `This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag` But i set esModuleInterop to true. how can i solve it?

Comment: Seems like tsc is compiling your node_modules folder. Try adding `skipLibCheck` to your tsconfig. But really, this should be it's own question ;)