# Property 'version' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have the following code

```
app.use(function (req: Request, res, next) {
  req.version = req.headers['accept-version'] || '1.0.0';
  next();
});
```

And I have the file *express.d.ts*

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface Request {
    version?: string | string[];
  }
}
```

and in *tsconfig.json*

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    // other options
    "typeRoots": ["./typings", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "typings/**/*"
  ],
```

This setup has fixed the issue

> Property 'version' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

in vscode itself. However the issue is being thrown in the terminal when doing `npm run start`, or `nodemon`.

Have I missed something?

Comment: I have the same error - it seems okay in vscode

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by noting the command that `nodemon` ran e.g. `npm run start:dev`

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src
```

Then using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926496/typescript-declaration-merging-fail-about-express-request)

I added the `-T` transpile only to the command and just used that instead.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start:dev": "ts-node -T -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src",
    ...
  },
```

Maybe there is a way to make `nodemon` do the right thing