# Property `user` does not exist on type `Session & Partial<SessionData>`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, session

I had a code in javascript and I'm trying to convert it to typescript

```js
route.get('/order', async(req,res) => {  
    var sessionData = req.session;
    if(typeof sessionData.user === 'undefined')
    {        
        res.redirect('/panel/login');
    }
```

this is a piece of my code that used to work correctly in `javascript` but now I get this error for the `user`:

> Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session &
> Partial'

I assume I should add types for the `sessionData` variable and `(req, res)` params but I don't know what type should exactly be assigned to it.

**PS: I know this question looks duplicated but I've tried solutions from other similar questions and it didn't work**

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the stack trace because I don't see why it would throw an error on a typeof. Maybe you're accessing it elsewhere and its null there.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As stated in the [express-session types comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-session/index.d.ts#L23), you have to use `Declaration merging`.

Here's how you can implement `Declaration merging` on `express-session`:

```
import session from 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
  export interface SessionData {
    user: { [key: string]: any };
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks

Comment: A special note to all that are using `ts-node-dev`. Take care if you add this in a new file that is not directly included in your entry file. `ts-node-dev` won't pick up any type changes while it's currently running. In fact it only compiles files that are included in the entry file and it works its way through the tree based on the imports/exports, so it doesn't know about types that aren't directly included in your project. tsc had no problem compiling and finding the new type, so from now on I'm using `ts-node-dev` only with the `--transpile-only` parameter and let tsc do the typechecking.

Comment: Excellent answer. I think the important thing to flag is the use of `import "express-session"` at the top of the declaration file.

Answer (score 21):

I just encountered the same issue as you. This seems to be a fairly recent issue: [see explanation here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/792).

To fix this I overloaded the module as described in the Github issue:

```
import "express-session";
declare module "express-session" {
  interface SessionData {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

Just replace `string` with whatever type you need for that field.

Also I have added `./typing-stubs` in `tsconfig.json`

```
"typeRoots": [
      "./typing-stubs",
      "./node_modules/@types"
]
```

Comment: how should i do it?
i mean should i write this code in a new file and import it to my main file ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ts; what I did is just put this in the same file where I do the `app.use(session(....))` and it worked. It's likely not the best way to do this but it fixed my issue.

Comment: `tsconfig.json` has a field named typeRoots, which is commented out by default. You can uncomment that field and add the folder/file where you define new types. Don't forget to add `node_modules/@types` since this is the default directory for where installed `@type` packages are located.

Comment: why don't I see any typeRoots? should I add it manually?

Answer (score 4):

Trace the source code you'll find such a comment:

```
    /**
     * This interface allows you to declare additional properties on your 
     * session object 
     * using [declaration merging] 
     * (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).
     *
     * @example
     * declare module 'express-session' {
     *     interface SessionData {
     *         views: number;
     *     }
     * }
     *
     */
    interface SessionData {
        cookie: Cookie;
    }
```

Go ahead and read the documentation; you'll find a module augmentation section: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation

Now, augment "SessionData" yourself and add "user" to it in:     **src/types/express-session/index.d.ts**:

```
import { SessionData } from "express-session"

declare module "express-session" {
    interface SessionData {
        user: { [key: string]: any }
    }
}
```

Your tsconfig.json should set types roots to include the declaration in your compilation:

```
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],
```

Answer (score 4):

I just did this

```
(req.session as ISession).UserName = payload.UserName;
(req.session as ISession).Email = payload.Email;
```

And then ISession is an export interface with this:

```
import { Session } from "express-session";

export interface ISession extends Session {
  UserName?: string;
  Email?: string;
}
```

All the other suggestions say to override the type declaration, those suggestions didn't work for me. This was the only thing that worked. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is for future reference, for someone who have done all the step above but keep failing (vscode doesn't show the error anymore but still failed), it maybe `ts-node` problem, add `--transpile-only` to your `package.json` script, like this: `nodemon --exec ts-node -T src/app.ts`.

Source: [Typescript Declaration Merging fail about Express Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62926496/typescript-declaration-merging-fail-about-express-request)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case (typescript: "~5.3"), I created a folder named `types` and added `index.ts` inside of it.

index.ts

```
import 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
interface Session {
  user: any;
  }
}
```

Then I edited `tsconfig.json` like this;

```
{
 .... other configs
 "include": ["src/**/*", "__tests__/**/*"],
 "files": ["src/types/index.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue recently and here is the solution i came up with.

```js
import { Request } from "express";
import { Session } from "express-session";

export type SessionWithUser = Session & { user: string | {}};

export type AuthRequest = Request & {
  session?: SessionWithUser;
  auth?: { user: string; permission_id: number };
};
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: create a ts file and copy the code above. then import it wherever you need it and set the req type to it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Session } from 'express-session';

export type MyContext = {
      req: Request & { session?: Session & { userId?: number } };
    };
```