# Typescript's declaration merging not working as expected using ts-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, session

For a project using the `express-session` package, I'm trying to mutate the `session` object by simply adding a user key.

```
req.session.user = 123;
```

Coming from [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65108033/2989034)  accepted answer, I understand I could use declaration merging to extend the `SessionData` interface, using my own interface.

Looking at various open-source projects, such as the [HospitalRun components repository](https://github.com/HospitalRun/components/tree/master) I notice them  having the `types` directory in their `tsconfig.json` file under the `include` section like this.

```
  "include": [
    "src",
    "types"
  ]
```

My whole `tsconfig.json` looks like this, which lives in the root of the project.

```
{
    "include": [
        "types",
        "src",
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "build",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    },
}
```

I tried doing the same, together a file called `express-session.d.ts` in the root of this folder (`~/types/`), having the following contents:

```
import session from 'express-session';

declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        user: any;
    }
}
```

However, the error I keep receiving is this.

```
 Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Session & Partial<SessionData>'
```

When I do however add this piece of code above the code I use for mutating my session object, I no longer have the problem. This doesn't seem like the right approach though.

Also, when I use `tsc src/index.ts --build` instead of `ts-node src/index.ts` it also works.

What am I doing wrong here? How can this be fixed? I also tried using the `typeRoots`, using the same folder.

Comment: Do you have a link to a web IDE that demonstrates this problem, or other [mcve] of your issue?  I suspect the issue is due to your configuration, which is hard to debug sight unseen.

Comment: @jcalz Added my example!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**LATEST UPDATE (08-MAY-2021)**

When running the typescript program by using `ts-node`, even `typeRoots` are specified in tsconfig.json, it cannot recognise the custom .d.ts and prompt `Property 'x` does not exist on type y` error.

According to https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/1132#issuecomment-716642560

One of the contributors of `ts-node` suggested multiple ways to solve it.

Here is one of it:
Specifying `file: true` flag in `tsconfig.json` to inform `ts-node` to load `files`, `include` and `exclude` options from `tsconfig.json` on startup

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "exclude": [...],
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
}
```

---

**OLD: (07-MAY-2021)**

There is no need to use `include` in `tsconfig.json` and the paths are not correct. The compiler can search the ts file in the directory and sub-directories

Try to remove it. and restart TS server.

If you are using VSCode, try <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and search `Restart TS server` and see if the user type error still exist

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "esnext.asynciterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "build",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't really understand.

Comment: remove the include part from tsconfig and restart visual code or restart TS server

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, still the same error.

Comment: i make a minimal example. and the type can be recognised successfully.
https://github.com/michael-vascue/express-type
  Take a look. Try to clone it and see if you have the same error on your side

Comment: If the example works, you can cross-check the differences. I follow all the data you provided to create it, so the only chance there is a difference is the packages' version

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, though, it still doesn't work. I mean, there is no syntax error, but on compilation using the `ts-node` package it gives the error.

Comment: try to use `ts-node --files main.ts` to ask ts-node to look into tsconfig.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232108/discussion-between-bas-and-mic-fung).