# Expending Request's interface seems to not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Hi I'm creating an api with Express and typescript and I'm trying to extend Request to add an user property. So I have search on google and find multiple posts on stackoverflow who explains how to do this but I have a weird error. I have declare my type so I can write req.user on vscode and I don't get any error. VScodre recognise that user is a property of Request but when I try to compile I have an error who indicate that my request object doesn't have a user property. It act like I didn't extend the Request object

here is my interface:

```
declare namespace Express{
  export interface Request{
    user: any;
  }
}
```

It is declare in an express.d.ts file directly

I also have edit my tsconfig file to add

```
"typeRoots": ["@types", "node_modules/@types", "./src"]
```

and here is the error message :

```
error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
```

Do you know what can cause that ?

Comment: are you using ts-node? If yes, read my previous response in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/67441138/15569492. should be similar issue where you need to set ts-node files flag to true

Comment: thanks it solved my problem

Comment: If you find it helpful, you can consider upvote my answer in that post to let's more people to be able to see it and search it :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you already solved the problem, but for future searches, I solved the problem thanks to these steps:

### Use the Correct File Path

The custom declaration has to be **inside the folder that will be compiled to JS** (the **'rootDir'** in your tsconfig.json). If, like me, you specified your root dir to be './src', the declaration must be inside the src folder. Otherwise, the compiler won't even look for the file.

Follow this directory structure to create the Express declaration file:

```
Directory
|-- src
|   |-- controllers
|   |-- utils
|   |-- @types
|   |   `-- express
|   |       `-- index.d.ts
|   `-- [...] 
|-- tsconfig.json
`-- [...]
```

Note that you have to put the name of the module as the folder name, in this case the path will be **./src/@types/express/index.d.ts**.

### Setup the declaration correctly

Note that you need to specify `export interface Request` and not just `interface Request`.

Furthermore, there must not be other imports outside the 'declare', otherwise the declaration will not be accessible globally anymore.

If you need to import something, do it below 'declare' to not break the declaration.

You do not need to do `declare global`, it will break the code.

```
declare namespace Express {
  // Import here any Interface you need
  import User from '../interfaces/user'

  export interface Request {
    user: User // specify your type here
  }
}
```

### Set up your **tsconfig.json** correctly

In your tsconfig.json file, insert these options:

```
{ 
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    // This is not necessary (my setup worked without it), but if yours doesn't it's worth a shot
    "typeRoots": ["typings", "node_modules/@types/"],
  },
  // This is important, to make the Compiler find the declaration. 
  // Without this, the compiler wouldn't be able to find your custom declaration and apply it
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
}
```